# KeyState condition is not working

Tags: c#, keyboard-events

I'm making a simple plane shooting game and want to move plane freely and fire at the same time but I'm able to move left + fire, Right + fire, up-left + fire, Down-left + fire but Down-Right + fire and Up-Right + fire conditions are not working have done all I can. Following is my code(here Boolean check is for fire):

**KeyDown:**

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {


            GetKeyboardState(keys);

            if ((keys[(int)Keys.Down] & 128) == 128)
            {
                moveDown = true;
                if ((keys[(int)Keys.Down] & keys[(int)Keys.Right] & 128) == 128)
                {

                    moveRight = true;
                }
                else if ((keys[(int)Keys.Down] & keys[(int)Keys.Left] & 128) == 128)
                {
                    moveLeft = true;
                }
                if ((keys[(int)Keys.Space] & 128) == 128)
                {
                    check = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("fire");
                }

            }
            else if ((keys[(int)Keys.Up] & 128) == 128)
            {

                    moveUp = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("up " + plane.Location.Y);

                    if ((keys[(int)Keys.Up] & keys[(int)Keys.Right] & 128) == 128)
                    {
                        moveRight = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("(" + plane.Location.X + "," + plane.Location.Y + ")");  
                    }

                    else if ((keys[(int)Keys.Up] & keys[(int)Keys.Left] & 128) == 128 )
                    {

                        moveLeft = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("(" + plane.Location.X + "," + plane.Location.Y + ")");
                    }

                    if ((keys[(int)Keys.Space] & 128) == 128)
                    {
                        check = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("fire");
                    }

             }

            else if ((keys[(int)Keys.Right] & 128) == 128)
            {

                        moveRight = true;
                if ((keys[(int)Keys.Space] & 128) == 128)
                {
                    check = true;
                }
            }

            else if ((keys[(int)Keys.Left] & 128) == 128)
            {
                    moveLeft = true;

                if ((keys[(int)Keys.Space] & 128) == 128)
                {
                    check = true;
                } 
            }
            else if ((keys[(int)Keys.Space] & 128) == 128)
            {
                    check = true;  
            }


        }
```

**Timer:**

```
private void shootTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (check == true)
            {
                checkShots();
            }

            moveShot();

            if (moveRight == true)
            {
                if (plane.Location.X < 545)
                {
                    plane.Location = new Point(plane.Location.X + 4, plane.Location.Y);
                    restartShot.Location = new Point(restartShot.Location.X + 4, restartShot.Location.Y);
                }
            }
            if (moveLeft == true)
            {
                if (plane.Location.X > 0)
                {
                    plane.Location = new Point(plane.Location.X - 4, plane.Location.Y);
                    restartShot.Location = new Point(restartShot.Location.X + 4, restartShot.Location.Y);
                }
            }
            if (moveUp == true)
            {
                if (plane.Location.Y > 0)
                {
                    plane.Location = new Point(plane.Location.X, plane.Location.Y - 4);
                    restartShot.Location = new Point(restartShot.Location.X, restartShot.Location.Y - 4);
                }
            }
            if (moveDown == true)
            {
                if (plane.Location.Y < 342)
                {
                    plane.Location = new Point(plane.Location.X, plane.Location.Y + 4);
                    restartShot.Location = new Point(restartShot.Location.X, restartShot.Location.Y + 4);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is limited by hardware. Keyboards usually use hardware matrix of keys and are driven by a very simple processor which doesn't allow arbitrary key combinations at once. You know, keyboards were originally for writing of text, where you never press more than one key + shift/alt/ctrl at once. The only safe solution of your problem is to use proper gaming device like a keypad.

And you can also try to buy a different keyboard - they are not the same. Same of them allow more keys at once than others. And it always depends on which particular keys do you press together. Some combinations work, some don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect [multiple-keypress](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7f4542f-c1c5-4cfa-ac04-521d4e7ef1a5/c-detect-multiple-keypress?forum=csharpgeneral) at the same time

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
        KeyUp += Form1_KeyUp;
        Load += Form1_Load;
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (keyleft && keyup)
        {
            Console.Beep(220, 300);
        }
    }
    bool keyup = false;
    bool keyleft = false;

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            keyup = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            keyleft = true;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            keyup = false;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            keyleft = false;
        }
    }
}
```